# Why Display Image on Image Control When "Relative Path" of Folder No Image? (ASP.NET WebForms)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

Folder_Code with Visual Studio 2010 and Code Load Image:
[Code Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B5cO.png)
Folder on PC containing CODE :
[Folder on PC contain Image save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBsu8.png)
**SQL FilePath and DataFile ( Byte ):**
[SQL FilePath and DataFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xepjk.png)
But, when running the code displayed on GridView and Image Control:
[Display GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0MDT.png)
[Display Image Cotrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFJnV.png)
help me, explain why there are no pictures in the folder but still display pictures on GridView and ImageControl

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10601203).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what we can see, it looks like the images used are saved in the database, and thus the "folder" is not being used. While the sql data table DID save the path name, it looks like that was for some other "unknown" reason, and that sql table looks to have saved the image in the database, and thus it does not use and ignores the path name used, but in fact the GV code must have a row data bound event, and in that event, the picture is pulled from the database and that is the image used in the GV.

So far? yes, it looks like images were/are/being stored and saved in the database, and the path name column in the database is not being used anymore.